# Click on Child Android

Tags: android

How click properly on child textview which currently name is test. Layout is generated programitically. I need get id of child element of LinearLayout, and then click on it. Any examples or solutions?

```
  ll = new LinearLayout(context);
    ll.setId(R.id.testing123);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    lp2.setMargins(30, 30, 30, 30);
    ll.setLayoutParams(lp2);
    ll_root.addView(ll);

    TextView test = new TextView(context);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp234 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    test.setText("TEST 123");
    test1.setId(R.id.a);
    test.setLayoutParams(lp234);
    test.setClickable(false);
    lp234.setMargins(20, 20, 30, 30);


    ll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.a:
                    Log.e("AAAA", "AAAA");
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
    ll.addView(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find a child of your linearlayout by using ll.findViewById(R.id.a) if that's what you're asking.  If not, could you please clarify?